# How to show answer has been given by creator of post

Tags: support, accepted-answer, self-answer

I had a question in which I figured out myself edited the post with the answer, how do I mark as solved?
[Link to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707385/failing-onpostexecute)

Comment: Don't put the answer in the question section. Please make your own answer by using the "Answer" button below.

Comment: I've rolled back your last edit. Please move that to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *self-answer*; post your solution as an answer, not as part of your question.

You can then also mark that answer as accepted (possibly after a waiting period).

Do note that your answer, like your question, is subject to voting; make sure you meet the quality standards of the site when you create an answer.

Answer (score 2):

**If** the question deals with an issue that is of **value to others** and you have a solution that is of value to others then you should answer it, with an actual answer which you will be able to mark as accepted. (Not by editing your question to add the answer to the question like you've already done.)

**Otherwise** please delete it.

The canonical example of a question and solution that are not of value to others is a problem caused by a typo. What are the chances someone is going to make the exact same typo you did and will find your question and answer then they look for a solution to their own problem? Close to none. (Just an example. I'm not saying your problem was the result of a typo.)